# Boost threads on Windows

Tags: c++, multithreading, boost

we are working on a project to generate a general thread class that permit us to process a set of interconnected data.
The basic idea is to evaluate in different threads only the datasets that are not connected and that can be simultaneously processed.
We developed a ThreadClass based on boost::thread and a OF_bmutex class based based on boost::mutex in order to perform logging operation.

The scheme of the code is in the linked pdf (http://cdm.unimore.it/dep/test.pd) while the skeleton of the main classes are below...

```
// encapsulate boost::mutex to log...
class OF_bmutex{

public:

    std::string  mutex_type;
    int m_id;
    boost::mutex  m;

    void  lock(){ 
       std::cout << "Mutex " << mutex_type << m_id << " locking from " << boost::this_thread::get_id() << std::endl;       
       m.lock();       
       std::cout << "Mutex " << mutex_type << m_id << " locked from " <<  boost::this_thread::get_id()  << std::endl; 
    }

    void  unlock(){ 
       std::cout <<  "Mutex "  << mutex_type << m_id << " unlocking from " << boost::this_thread::get_id() << std::endl;
       m.unlock(); 
       std::cout << "Mutex " << mutex_type << m_id << " unlocked from " << boost::this_thread::get_id() << std::endl;
    }

    bool  try_lock(){ 
        std::cout <<  "Mutex " << mutex_type << m_id << " try locking from " <<  boost::this_thread::get_id() << std::endl;
        bool ret = m.try_lock();
        if( ret ){ 
            std::cout << "Mutex " << mutex_type << m_id << " try locked from " << boost::this_thread::get_id() << std::endl;
        }
        return(ret);
    }
 };




// My thread class
class OF_ThreadClass {
    private:
        //! running variable
        bool running;
        //! The thread executing this process...
        boost::thread *m_thread;
        //! The data to process...
        LinkedDataSet *my_data;
        //! The id of this thread
        int thread_id;
        //! Process the data...
        virtual int processData();
    public:
        //! The boost thread id
        boost::thread::id   boost_id;
        //! Thread function
        void operator () ();
        //! Default constructor
        OF_ThreadClass();
        //! Destructor
        ~OF_ThreadClass();
        //! Connect this thread with the process data to evaluate 
        void setProcessData( DataToProcess *pd );
        //! return the thread id
        int getId() const { return this->thread_id; }
        //! post process the thread...
        void post_process();
};




// The core function with the execution point of the Thread class...
void  OF_ThreadClass::operator () (){

    while( this->running ){

        OF_AVAILABLE_THREADS_MUTEX[ this->thread_id ]->unlock();
        OF_RUNNING_THREADS_MUTEX[ this->thread_id ]->lock();

        // PUT HERE OUR CODE...
        if( running == true ){
            if( my_data != NULL ){
                this->processData();
            }
            this->my_data->done = true;
        }
        std::cout << ">>>>>> Thread " << thread_id << " notified that evaluation terminated\n"; 

        OF_RUNNING_THREADS_MUTEX[ this->thread_id ]->unlock();              
        OF_AVAILABLE_THREADS_MUTEX[ this->thread_id ]->lock();
    }
    OF_AVAILABLE_THREADS_MUTEX[ this->thread_id ]->unlock();
}




// A class to perform multithread calculation...
class OF_SmartThreads{
    private:

    //! The number of threads to activate
    int     _n_threads;
    //! The polling time
    int     _polling_time;
    //! The thread pool...
    std::vector< OF_ThreadClass *> threadPool;

    //! The stack of the available threads 
    std::set< OF_ThreadClass *> *OF_AVAILABLE_THREADS;
    //! The set of the running threads
    std::set< OF_ThreadClass *> OF_RUNNING_THREADS;

    //! The set of the locked datasets
    std::set< LinkedDataSet* >  locked_data;
    //! The set of the available datasets
    std::set< LinkedDataSet* >  unlocked_data;
    //! The set of the datasets under processing
    std::set< LinkedDataSet* >  processing_data;

    //! The size of the progress bar
    int progBarDim;

    public:
    //! Constructor
    OF_SmartThreads();
    //! Destructor
    ~OF_SmartThreads();

    //! Initialize the SmartThreads
    int init_function( std::list< LinkedDataSet * > *dList, int n_max_threads);
    //! Initialize the SmartThreads
    int init_function( std::set< LinkedDataSet * > *dSet, int n_max_threads);

    //! Process all the cuncurrent threads..
    int process_data();
    //! Process all the cuncurrent threads..
    int process_data_polling( int polling_time );
    //! stop the process..
    int post_process();
};




// Initialization function...
int OF_SmartThreads::init_function( ... ){

    // in the main thread...

    // Fill the pool of thread mutex...
    for(int i = 0; i< _n_threads; i++ ){

        _tm = new OF_BMUTEX;
        _tm->mutex_type.assign( "A" );
        _tm->m_id = i;
        OF_AVAILABLE_THREADS_MUTEX.push_back( _tm );

        _tm = new OF_BMUTEX;
        _tm->mutex_type.assign( "R" );
        _tm->m_id = i;
        OF_RUNNING_THREADS_MUTEX.push_back( _tm );
    }

    // Create the threads...
    threadPool.resize( _n_threads );
    for(int i = 0; i< _n_threads; i++ ){

        // ...preventivally lock the resources...
        OF_RUNNING_THREADS_MUTEX[i]->lock();
        OF_AVAILABLE_THREADS_MUTEX[i]->unlock();

        // ..create the new thread...
        pc = new OF_ThreadClass;
        // insert the new thread in the list...
        threadPool.at( pc->getId() ) = pc;
        // set it as available...
        OF_AVAILABLE_THREADS->insert( pc );
    }
}



// Execution function...
void process_data_polling( int _polling_time ){
    while ( running ){
        if ( something_changed ){   

            //Print the status on the screen...
            ...
        }

        something_changed = false;

        // Poll the status of the processing data periodically      
        boost::this_thread::sleep(boost::posix_time::millisec( _polling_time ));

        // Are there some data ready to process?
        if( OF_UNLOCKED_DATASETS->size() > 0 ){

            // Take the first 
            pd = *OF_UNLOCKED_DATASETS->begin();

            // are there some threads available?
            if( OF_AVAILABLE_THREADS->size() != 0 ){

                //...lock and move the datasets linked to pd...
                ret = lock_data( pd, LOCK ); 

                std::cout << "\tNumber of available threads: " << OF_AVAILABLE_THREADS->size() << std::endl;

                // Take the available thread...
                pc = *OF_AVAILABLE_THREADS->begin();

                // ...link it the dataset to process...
                pc->setProcess( pd );

                OF_AVAILABLE_THREADS_MUTEX[ pc->getId() ]->lock();

                OF_RUNNING_THREADS_MUTEX[ pc->getId() ]->unlock();

                something_changed = true;

            } // available threads  
        } // unlock datasets



        // Find, unlock and remove finished datasets...
        pIter2  = OF_RUNNING_THREADS->begin();
        pEnd2   = OF_RUNNING_THREADS->end();
        while( pIter2 != pEnd2 ){
            pc = *pIter2++;
            pd = pc->getDataSet();

            if( pd->isDone() ){

                //...unlock and move the datasets linked to the current dataset...
                ret_move = lock_data( pd, RELEASE_LOCK ); 

                //...remove the data from the active set
                ret_remove = OF_ACTIVE_DATASETS->erase( pd );

                // make the threads available
                moveThreads( pc, _RUNNING_, _AVAILABLE_ );

                something_changed = true;
            }
        }



        pIter2  = OF_AVAILABLE_THREADS->begin();
        pEnd2   = OF_AVAILABLE_THREADS->end();
        while( pIter2 != pEnd2 ){
            pc = *pIter2++;

            bool obtained = OF_RUNNING_THREADS_MUTEX[ pc->getId() ]->try_lock();
            if( obtained ){
                std::cout << "\t\t\tOF_SMART_THREADS: Thread " << pc->getId() << " obtained running mutex..." << std::endl;
            }
            else{
                std::cout << "\t\t\tOF_SMART_THREADS: Thread " << pc->getId() << " failed to obtain running mutex..." << std::endl;
            }
            OF_AVAILABLE_THREADS_MUTEX[ pc->getId() ]->unlock();
            std::cout << "\t\t\tOF_SMART_THREADS: Thread " << pc->getId() << " released available mutex..." << std::endl;
        }

        if(  ( OF_LOCKED_DATASETS->size() + OF_UNLOCKED_DATASETS->size() + OF_ACTIVE_DATASETS->size() ) > 0 ){
            running = true;
        }
        else{
            running = false;
        }

    } // end running...
}



// The main function...
int main( int argc, char* argv[]) {

    init_function( &data, INT_MAX );

    process_data_polling( 100 );

    lc.post_process();

    return 0;
}
```

all the system function perfectly when compiled on Linux and OSX with boost 1.53. The number of threads used is 2. An extract of the log is presented below.
Note the mutex logs emitted from the proper threads...

```
---> LOG FROM OSX ...

 ---------------------------------
 Number of data: 2
Data: 0, links: 
Data: 1, links: 

---> OF_SmartThreads::init_function --
 ------------------------------------
 --> 8 processors/cores detected.
 --> n_max_threads = 2
 ------------------------------------
                Mutex R0 locking from thread master 
                Mutex R0 locked from thread master 
                Mutex R0 try locking from thread master 
            OF_SMART_THREADS: Thread 0 failed to obtain running mutex...
                Mutex A0 unlocking from thread master 
                Mutex A0 unlocked from thread master 
 New thread 0 created 
                Mutex R1 locking from thread master 
                Mutex R1 locked from thread master 
                Mutex R1 try locking from thread master 
            OF_SMART_THREADS: Thread 1 failed to obtain running mutex...
                Mutex A1 unlocking from thread master 
                Mutex A1 unlocked from thread master 
 New thread 1 created 
 ---------------------------------
Available threads: 2
Unlocked datasets: 2


---> OF_SmartThreads::process_data_function

                Mutex A1 unlocking from thread1
                Mutex A1 unlocked from thread1
>>>>>> Thread 1 released available mutex...
                Mutex R1 locking from thread1
                Mutex A0 unlocking from thread0
                Mutex A0 unlocked from thread0
>>>>>> Thread 0 released available mutex...
                Mutex R0 locking from thread0

 UNLOCKED DATASETS : 0 1 
 LOCKED DATASETS   : 
 ACTIVE DATASETS   : 
 RUNNING THREADS   : 
    OF_SMART_THREADS: THREADS AVAILABLE
    Number of available threads: 2
    OF_SMART_THREADS: take the thread 0
    OF_SMART_THREADS: Thread master try to lock available mutex... 0
                Mutex A0 locking from thread master 
                Mutex A0 locked from thread master 
    OF_SMART_THREADS: Thread obtained available mutex... 0
    OF_SMART_THREADS: Thread try to unlock running mutex... 0
                Mutex R0 unlocking from thread master 
                Mutex R0 unlocked from thread master 
    OF_SMART_THREADS: Thread released running mutex... 0

            OF_SMART_THREADS: PREPARE AVAILABLE THREADS
                Mutex R1 try locking from thread master 
            OF_SMART_THREADS: Thread 1 failed to obtain running mutex...
                Mutex A1 unlocking from thread master 
                Mutex A1 unlocked from thread master 
            OF_SMART_THREADS: Thread 1 released available mutex...

 UNLOCKED DATASETS : 1 
 LOCKED DATASETS   : 
 ACTIVE DATASETS   : 0 
 RUNNING THREADS   : 0->0 
                Mutex R0 locked from thread0
>>>>>> Thread 0 obtained running mutex...
>>>>>> Thread 0 is going to process the dataset 0
>>>>>> Thread 0 terminated to process the dataset 0
>>>>>> Thread 0 notified that evaluation terminated
                Mutex R0 unlocking from thread0
                Mutex R0 unlocked from thread0
>>>>>> Thread 0 released running mutex...
                Mutex A0 locking from thread0
    OF_SMART_THREADS: THREADS AVAILABLE
    Number of available threads: 1
    OF_SMART_THREADS: take the thread 1
    OF_SMART_THREADS: Thread master try to lock available mutex... 1
                Mutex A1 locking from thread master 
                Mutex A1 locked from thread master 
    OF_SMART_THREADS: Thread obtained available mutex... 1
    OF_SMART_THREADS: Thread try to unlock running mutex... 1
                Mutex R1 unlocking from thread master 
                Mutex R1 unlocked from thread master 
    OF_SMART_THREADS: Thread released running mutex... 1

        OF_SMART_THREADS: CHECK THREADS DONE
        ------------> DATASETS 0 done...
        ------------> DATASETS 0 removed from the active set. 

            OF_SMART_THREADS: PREPARE AVAILABLE THREADS
                Mutex R0 try locking from thread master 
                Mutex R0 try locked from thread master 
            OF_SMART_THREADS: Thread 0 obtained running mutex...
                Mutex R1 locked from thread1
                Mutex A0 unlocking from thread master 
>>>>>> Thread 1 obtained running mutex...
                Mutex A0 unlocked from thread master 
>>>>>> Thread 1 is going to process the dataset 1
                Mutex A0 locked from thread0
            OF_SMART_THREADS: Thread 0 released available mutex...
>>>>>> Thread 0 obtained available mutex...

 UNLOCKED DATASETS : 
 LOCKED DATASETS   : 
 ACTIVE DATASETS   : 1 
 RUNNING THREADS   : 1->1 
>>>>>> Thread 1 terminated to process the dataset 1
                Mutex A0 unlocking from thread0
>>>>>> Thread 1 notified that evaluation terminated
                Mutex A0 unlocked from thread0
                Mutex R1 unlocking from thread1
>>>>>> Thread 0 released available mutex...
                Mutex R1 unlocked from thread1
                Mutex R0 locking from thread0
>>>>>> Thread 1 released running mutex...
                Mutex A1 locking from thread1

        OF_SMART_THREADS: CHECK THREADS DONE
        ------------> DATASETS 1 done...
        ------------> DATASETS 1 removed from the active set. 

            OF_SMART_THREADS: PREPARE AVAILABLE THREADS
                Mutex R0 try locking from thread master 
            OF_SMART_THREADS: Thread 0 failed to obtain running mutex...
                Mutex A0 unlocking from thread master 
                Mutex A0 unlocked from thread master 
            OF_SMART_THREADS: Thread 0 released available mutex...
                Mutex R1 try locking from thread master 
                Mutex R1 try locked from thread master 
            OF_SMART_THREADS: Thread 1 obtained running mutex...
                Mutex A1 unlocking from thread master 
                Mutex A1 unlocked from thread master 
            OF_SMART_THREADS: Thread 1 released available mutex...

OF_SMART_THREADS: ALL THE DATASETS HAS BEEN SUCCESFULLY PROCESSED...


                Mutex A1 locked from thread1
                Mutex R0 unlocking from thread master 
>>>>>> Thread 1 obtained available mutex...
                Mutex R0 unlocked from thread master 
                Mutex R0 locked from thread0
                Mutex A1 unlocking from thread1
>>>>>> Thread 0 obtained running mutex...
                Mutex A1 unlocked from thread1
>>>>>> Thread 0 notified that evaluation terminated
>>>>>> Thread 1 released available mutex...
                Mutex R0 unlocking from thread0
                Mutex R1 locking from thread1
                Mutex R0 unlocked from thread0
>>>>>> Thread 0 released running mutex...
                Mutex A0 locking from thread0
                Mutex A0 locked from thread0
>>>>>> Thread 0 obtained available mutex...
                Mutex A0 unlocking from thread0
                Mutex A0 unlocked from thread0
>>>>>> Thread 0 is terminating...
                Mutex R1 unlocking from thread master 
                Mutex R1 unlocked from thread master 
                Mutex R1 locked from thread1
>>>>>> Thread 1 obtained running mutex...
>>>>>> Thread 1 notified that evaluation terminated
                Mutex R1 unlocking from thread1
                Mutex R1 unlocked from thread1
>>>>>> Thread 1 released running mutex...
                Mutex A1 locking from thread1
                Mutex A1 locked from thread1
>>>>>> Thread 1 obtained available mutex...
                Mutex A1 unlocking from thread1
                Mutex A1 unlocked from thread1
>>>>>> Thread 1 is terminating...
```

The problem arise when compiling system on Windows 7, both with Visual Studio 64 bits and with Mingw 32 bit. As it is possible to see from the log before
there is a deadlock at the beginning. This appears to us very strange and cannot be explained by the mutex logs coming from the different threads.
Some suggestion on how to debug this problem?

```
---> LOG FROM WINDOWS 7...


 ---------------------------------
 Number of data: 2
Data: 0, links:
Data: 1, links:

-———> OF_SmartThreads::init_function --
 ------------------------------------
 --> 4 processors/cores detected.
 --> n_max_threads = 2
 ------------------------------------
                                Mutex R0 locking from thread master
                                Mutex R0 locked from thread master
                                Mutex R0 try locking from thread master
                        OF_SMART_THREADS: Thread 0 failed to obtain running mutex...
                                Mutex A0 unlocking from thread master
                                Mutex A0 unlocked from thread master
 New thread 0 created
                                Mutex A0 unlocking from thread0
                                Mutex A0 unlocked from thread0
                                Mutex R1 locking from thread master
                                Mutex R1 locked from thread master
>>>>>> Thread 0 released available mutex...
                                Mutex R0 locking from thread0
                                Mutex R1 try locking from thread master
                        OF_SMART_THREADS: Thread 1 failed to obtain running mutex...
                                Mutex A1 unlocking from thread master
                                Mutex A1 unlocked from thread master
 New thread 1 created
                                Mutex A1 unlocking from thread1
                                Mutex A1 unlocked from thread1
 ---------------------------------
Available threads: 2
>>>>>> Thread 1 released available mutex...
                                Mutex R1 locking from thread1
Unlocked datasets: 2

---> OF_SmartThreads::process_data_function


 UNLOCKED DATASETS : 0 1
 LOCKED DATASETS   :
 ACTIVE DATASETS   :
 RUNNING THREADS   :
        OF_SMART_THREADS: THREADS AVAILABLE
        Number of available threads: 2
        OF_SMART_THREADS: take the thread 0
        OF_SMART_THREADS: Thread master try to lock available mutex... 0
                                Mutex A0 locking from thread master
                                Mutex A0 locked from thread master
        OF_SMART_THREADS: Thread obtained available mutex... 0
        OF_SMART_THREADS: Thread try to unlock running mutex... 0
                                Mutex R0 unlocking from thread master
                                Mutex R0 unlocked from thread master
                                Mutex R0 locked from thread0
        OF_SMART_THREADS: Thread released running mutex... 0
>>>>>> Thread 0 obtained running mutex...
>>>>>> Thread 0 is going to process the dataset 0
 Process Data: delay 41

                        OF_SMART_THREADS: PREPARE AVAILABLE THREADS
>>>>>> Thread 0 terminated to process the dataset 0
>>>>>> Thread 0 notified that evaluation terminated
                                Mutex R1 try locking from thread master
                        OF_SMART_THREADS: Thread 1 failed to obtain running mutex...
                                Mutex A1 unlocking from thread master
                                Mutex A1 unlocked from thread master
                                Mutex R0 unlocking from thread0
                                Mutex R0 unlocked from thread0
                        OF_SMART_THREADS: Thread 1 released available mutex...

 UNLOCKED DATASETS : 1
 LOCKED DATASETS   :
 ACTIVE DATASETS   : 0*
 RUNNING THREADS   : 0->0
>>>>>> Thread 0 released running mutex...
                                Mutex A0 locking from thread0
        OF_SMART_THREADS: THREADS AVAILABLE
        Number of available threads: 1
        OF_SMART_THREADS: take the thread 1
        OF_SMART_THREADS: Thread master try to lock available mutex... 1
                                Mutex A1 locking from thread master
```

There is a deadlock, the thread master cannot lock mutex A1 but, as you can see from the log, no other threads locked that mutex before. Some suggestions on how to debug this problem?

Regards

Comment: You can not prove there is or there isn't a deadlock by `cout`s. Some of them are synchronized and some are not. You have no guarantee to the order of printing of half the debugs.

Comment: The deadlock is proven by the fact that execution hangs. About the synchronizations: I removed another mutex to synchronize the cout from the code to improve readability, the result is the same

Answer (score 1):

Add lock monitoring to your `OF_bmutex`, like `bool locked`. You should not unclock not locked mutex, or lock locked mutex - so place `assert`. It seems like your `init_function` does `OF_AVAILABLE_THREADS_MUTEX[i]->unlock();` without prior lock.

[Boost BasicLockable Concept](http://www.boost.org/doc/libs/1_54_0/doc/html/thread/synchronization.html#thread.synchronization.mutex_concepts.basic_lockable.unlock):

```
m.unlock();
```

> Requires: **The current thread owns m**

So looks like you are violating `unlock()` preconditions. That can be seen in your log:

```
Mutex A0 unlocking from thread master 
Mutex A0 unlocked from thread master
```

Comment: Thanks Evgeny, I will fix the bad initialization procedure. It is not clear to me how the boolean variable and the assert statement can help me in the debugging...

Comment: @GabrieleCuccolini Add flag `bool locked;` to `OF_bmutex`. In constructor set it to `false`. In `lock()` add code `assert(!locked); locked = true;`, in unlock add `assert(locked); locked = false;`, etc.